# What does 「どっか」 mean?

Tags: meaning, particle-の, listening

In this clip [at 19:50](https://youtu.be/ZgE387KDVpU?t=19m50s), it sounds like he is saying, "Nante na! Kore *dokka* no kiza na yatsu ga itteta serifu" ("This is just something a ____ pretentious guy said"). Is it indeed 「どっか」 ? What does that mean?

I tried looking up 「どっか」in 2 online dictionaries but I did not find a clear definition. Is it at all related to phrases like 「どっか行け」 or 「椅子にどっかり座る」? Since it is followed by the particle 「の」, I would imagine not...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

どっか is the short spoken form of どこか which means `somewhere`.

There is also an entry here: http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%95%E5%87%A6%E3%81%8B